# Puedo cambiar el valor del constructor de forma definitiva?

Tags: java

A ver mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo una clase la cual tiene en su constructor un modificador de un parámetro de su superclase, me gustaría poder cambiar ese parámetro de forma definitiva.
Es decir, el ejemplo es, tengo una clase Mesa que tiene campos de Tipo y Precio.
y luego tengo una subclase Comedor, que modifica al crear tipo por Mesa de Comedor y el Precio por el estipulado. Así:

```
public class Comedor extends Mesa {

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Comedor
     */
    public Comedor(int id)
    {
        super(id);
        ambito = "Comedor";
        precio = 105;
    }
```

Mi pregunta es como podría cambiar ese 105, por otra cantidad de tal manera que el constructor cuando me cree nuevos objetos cambie el precio de todos los objetos en adelante. La unica forma que se me ocurre es creando fuera en el controlador una constante que sea el precio, y cada vez que cree una mesa comedor le pase el precio. ¿Habría otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Aquí lo que interesa saber de ese precio, es ¿cómo lo quieres modficar? Es decir, es un valor que va a estar en base de datos, es un valor que va a estar en fichero a parte (properties, xml...), es un valor que va estar en código pero que no quieres que esté en la misma clase, es un valor variable, que dentro del programa va a poder cambiarse cuando ocurra algo...?

Comment: a ver me estoy inciando en esto de java y es basicamente un ejercicio, por lo tanto estoy creando un programa que gestione una fabrica de muebles. Muy simple, hago pedidos de muebles, gestion empleados etc etc.
Habia creado subclases por cada tipo de mueble, de tal modo que al agregar un pedido de X mueble se crea su objeto con sus propiedades, y uno de ellos es el campo precio, que lo inicio en su constructor en este caso con 105, por lo tanto, todas las mesas comedor que agregue en pedidos tendran ese precio.
Podria crear algún método que me modifique ese valor que el constructor asigna?

Answer (score 0):

Sigue sin quedarme muy clara la pregunta, pero te voy a poner unos ejemplos a ver si te valen. El primer caso lo puedes usar **si sabes el precio que va a tener un Comedor en el momento de la creación**.

```
public Comedor(int id, int precio) {
    super(id);
    ambito = "Comedor";
    this.precio = precio;
}
```

En este primer ejemplo fuerzas a que el que cree un objeto de tipo `Comedor` le tenga que pasar el precio, por lo que tendrá que hacer algo así:

```
Comedor c1 = new Comedor(1, 100);
Comedor c2 = new Comedor(2, 105);
```

¿Qué pasa si no sabes el precio en el momento de crear el comedor? Puedes delegar esa responsabilidad a otra clase:

```
public Comedor(int id, int precio) {
    super(id);
    ambito = "Comedor";
    this.precio = GestorPrecios.getPrecio(ambito);
}
```

Lógicamente te tendrás que crear una clase parecida e implementar el método donde devuelvas el precio. Puedes aprovechar esta clase para obtener el valor del precio desde un fichero properties, de base de datos, de un fichero, de un servicio web...

Si no quieres delegarlo a otra clase, puedes tenerlo también en la propia clase en un contexto estático:

```
public class Comedor extends Mesa {

    private static int PRECIO_COMEDOR = 105; // Precio por defecto.

    public static void cambiarPrecio(int nuevoPrecio) {
      PRECIO_COMEDOR = nuevoPrecio;
    }

    public Comedor(int id) {
        super(id);
        ambito = "Comedor";
        precio = PRECIO_COMEDOR;
    }

}
```

Si lo haces de esta manera, los primeros objetos que crees tendrán el precio por defecto, y si llamas al método estático `cambiarPrecio`, cambiarás el precio de todos los nuevos objetos que crees:

```
Comedor c1 = new Comedor(1);
Comedor.cambiarPrecio(100);
Comedor c2 = new Comedor(2);
Comedor c3 = new Comedor(3);
System.out.println(c1.getPrecio());
System.out.println(c2.getPrecio());
System.out.println(c3.getPrecio());
```

La salida es:

```
105
100
100
```

Fíjate que es necesario usar el modificador `static` para la variable `PRECIO_COMEDOR` y para el método `cambiarPrecio`. El motivo es que esa variable queremos que tenga un valor que se comparta entre todos los objetos de la misma clase. Para cambiar un valor estático hay que hacerlo desde un método estático, por lo que el método también lleva el modificador `static`.

Más info:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html